# I am trying to pass an unknown variable from one HTML page to another HTML page

Tags: html, coldfusion

This is the code I have on the first page

```
<body onload=setTimeout("location.href='http://64.124.162.184/TrenaTest/testformtwo.htm'?UniqueNum=#form.UniqueNum#",3000) bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
```

Then when I go to the next page I have

```
<cfif isdefined("form.UniqueNum") and len(form.UniqueNum)> 
#form.UniqueNum# 
</cfif>
```

It doesn't give me any errors I just get `NULL`.

Comment: What server side technology are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Use url.uniqueNum instead.  Since you are passing it in the url param it is not in the form scope it is in the url scope.

And like Scott says, you need to nest the variables in a cfoutput tag for them to display.  To help you troubleshoot, you can dump the scopes to see what is them:

```
<cfdump var="#variables#">
<cfdump var="#form#">
<cfdump var="#url#">
<cfdump var="#session#">
<cfdump var="#application#">
<cfdump var="#server#">
```

Comment: @trlewis can you be more descriptive as to what happened?

Answer (score 4):

You have a JS syntax error with a single tick in the wrong spot.

```
<body onload=setTimeout("location.href='http://64.124.162.184/TrenaTest/testformtwo.htm'?UniqueNum=#form.UniqueNum#",3000) bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
```

That single tick after the .htm is probably your culprit. Move it to the end - after #form.uniqueNum# so it looks like this:

`<body onload=setTimeout("location.href='http://64.124.162.184/TrenaTest/testformtwo.htm?UniqueNum=#form.UniqueNum#'",3000) bgcolor="#FFFFFF"`>

Then, as Tim has said, your vars will be in the *URL* scope - not in the *form* scope (this is a GET and not a POST)

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the #form.uniqueNum# in <cfoutput> tags other wise it will simply be sending the string '#form.uniqueNum#' rather than the value of form.uniqueNum.

Might want to make sure the value exists before hand too, maybe use <cfparam>.

Also, what is 'the next page'? I assume you mean what happens when the timeout is 'fired'. That page has a .htm file extension so its not likely to be processed by ColdFusion.

Comment: Yes the next pag is what happens when it times out.

Comment: OK, try wrapping the variable in the URL in setTimeout() in <cfoutput> tags then in the 'next page' you need to reference URL scope as Tim said.

Answer (score 0):

Hey why is your page "testformtwo.**htm**". it should be testformtwo.**cfm** i suppose. unless you have mapped the htm to be processed as cfm in the server config.